# Spring MVC ?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring, github, java

Можете посоветовать пример приложения которое можно взять за основу своего(бывают такие примеры на гитхабе, но я чего то не нашел) . Где грамотно описана работа с бд, с самим спрингом и тд.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чем вам не нравятся примеры на сайте spring [Spring Tutorials](http://spring.io/guides#tutorials) ?

Comment: Вполне вменяемые примеры http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/web/

Step 1: Modelling the Core and Web Domains 
Step 2: Implementing URLs and returning data
Step 3: Configuring a basic application
Step 4: Creating rich HTML views using Thymeleaf
Step 5: Accepting user submitted data
Step 6: Securing the Web Application
Recap and What's Next?

Comment: там язык непонятный

Answer (score 0):

Посоветую взять примеры из книги "Spring 4 для профессионалов" авторов  Крис Шефер, Кларенс Хо, Роб Харроп.

Сам учился по ней.

Все, что вы перечислили есть в этой книге и довольно неплохо описывается. Там есть и про сам Spring и про работу с БД.